# create Yii url route with multible parameters

Tags: php, yii

I have controller named **pagesController** and I have action inside controller named actionSite 
how can I create route rule to the **pagesController** and **ActionSite** with two parameter the first one is **name_en** and the second one is **id**

my route should be **'/pages/site/os1w/10'**

```
pages is controller 
site is action 
oslw is the value of name_en param
id is the value of id param
```

so I have to get the values of parameter as follow :

```
name_en = $_GET['name_en']; //it return oslw
id      = $_GET['id']; // it return 10
```

My config looks like this:

```
'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
 ),
```

I tried

```
'/pages/site/<name_en:\w+><id:\w+>'=>'mysite/login',
```

but it return Unable to resolve the request

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost right but try this

```
'/pages/site/<name_en:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'payfort/login',
```

I have just added a `/` in between `<name_en:\w+>/<id:\d+>` and instead of using `\w+` with `<id:`, you should use `\d+`